# Vaadin + GAE + blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, vaadin, blobstore

Anybody was successful to use vaadin with GAE and blobstore. Iam currently stuck in it. Beside Upload component of Vaadin doesnt work on GAE as it uses fileinput&output stream. I don't want to go into the details of implementing my own communicationmanager for the application and then ovverride handleUpload method. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/126142;jsessionid=1C7766921D6772D1774B476C724196CB